# Shorter alternative to CASE expression WHEN?

Tags: sql, oracle, case, netsuite

I have a SQL expression to map some data from one format to another:

```sql
CASE field
WHEN 'AU' THEN '036'
WHEN 'AT' THEN '040'
WHEN 'BE' THEN '056'
-- and so on
END
```

Unfortunately I need to fit this expression into a length-limited text box (a NetSuite formula field) and with the number of options I have it doesn't fit. Is there a less verbose alternative in Oracle to the CASE expression so I can write this using fewer characters?

Comment: Writing it as a `decode` may work.  But this seems to scream out for a translation table of some sort rather than a very long `decode` statement.

Comment: @JustinCave I agree, but unfortunately NetSuite doesn't have a way of joining tables inside a formula... the system tries to hide the database which makes it incredibly annoying for those of us who are used to SQL.

Comment: @Wolfgang - you could add a view that does the translation, via a join; and query that view instead?

Comment: Does it also have no way to call a function which would query a translation table?

Comment: @AlexPoole It doesn't give any access to the underlying database to create a view, either.

Comment: @JustinCave Not as far as I can tell, no. Formulas don't have access to data outside of the current row and rows linked to it by foreign keys, and since the point of this mapping is to figure out what the foreign key is supposed to be that doesn't help me.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, use the [`DECODE()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm):

```sql
DECODE(field,
'AU', '036',
'AT', '040',
'BE', '056'
)
```